# AngularJS: How to make parent directive using transclusion be compiled before the child directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following structure:

```
<dad-dir>
  <kid-dir></bar-dir>
  <kid-dir></bar-dir>
</dad-dir>
```

Here, `dadDir` is the parent directive, and `kidDir` is the child directive. In `dadDir`, `transclude` is set to true. The output looks something like this:

```
<div class='dad-dir'>
  <span class='kid-dir'>Kid directive output</span>
  <span class='kid-dir'>Kid directive output</span>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is, the `kidDir`s are being compiled / linked before `dadDir`. This is a problem because I want `dadDir` to set certain attributes which I want `kidDir`s to inherit. I have a `console.log` line in the `link` functions of both `dadDir` and `kidDir` and the ones in `kidDir` are logged before `dadDir`'s.

I have tried changing the priority, setting `dadDir`'s priority to 10 and `kidDir`'s to 1, but it has no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: '^fooDir' is the proper notion.  how are you using the foodir, linking a function or just replacing some stuff?

Comment: because in the foo-dir directive definition, you have to define the controller, and then use that in bar-dir, link:

Comment: @kangoroo I do have a controller defined in parent directive

Comment: how about your controller?  why do you get a controller error?

Comment: check the controller function name attached to the body or whatever

Comment: @kangoroo The controller is fine, the child directives are being compiled before the parent directive

Comment: there is no such a thing, angular handles your compiling properly, your complete code would be helpful

Comment: @kangoroo Doing `console.log()` from the link function of both the child directive and parent directive, the lines from the child directive is logged before the parent directive.

Comment: that's why some more code would be wonderful :)  or you figure it out buddy.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was a bug in angularjs version 1.0.5 that I was previously using. I just upgraded to 1.2 and magically, `require: '^dadDir`' from `kidDir` works.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to transclude in the mother element ?

in fooDir Directive:

```
transclude: true
replace: true
template: "<div ng-transclude></div>"
```

and after in the child
barDir Directive

```
require: '^fooDir'
```

Comment: that's exactly what i'm doing, but the `require` in the child barDir gives me the error: `no controller fooDir`'